# What's the maximum number of slots for a multi-tool?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I found a multi-tool with 24 slots, and they are in a nice 3x8 formation with no holes. I haven't seen any bigger tools since I got this one, when I was regularly finding bigger tools before. Is this the largest size, or are there bigger ones?

Answer (score 12):

That's the cap, 24 for multi-tools and 48 for suit/ship.